# Как выполнить метод с аргументами из строки

Tags: javascript, парсер

Имеется строка вида `methodName(arg1,arg2)`. Каким образом можно распарсить строку для получения имя метода/функции с аргументами и выполнить полученный код?
К примеру имеется строка `plus(1,2)`. Из неё необходимо получить `plus` и массив аргументов.

Comment: вы сначала прочтите хоть что-то про js, а потом вопросы задавайте. Например тут [learn.javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru/first-steps)

Comment: ввел куда??????

Comment: Ну...например в prompt.

Comment: Вот это поворот

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/ymg9vp6o

Comment: почитайте про регулярки